# Multiple edit files without change '.DS_Store'

Tags: python

I am trying to rename multiple file by delete some first 9 letters, however there is a unseen file called '.DS_Store' which rise error. is there any way avoid that file to run the code like 'if...than...' something? code is like:

```
import os

os.chdir('/Users/pgao/Google Drive/Piano Sheet/Be Our Guest')

for f in os.listdir():
        new_name = f[9:]
        os.rename(f, new_name)
```

the list of that dir is:

```
WechatIMG149.jpeg
.DS_Store
WechatIMG152.jpeg
WechatIMG148.jpeg
WechatIMG147.jpeg
WechatIMG151.jpeg
WechatIMG150.jpeg
WechatIMG146.jpeg
```

it rise error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReEdit.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.rename(f, new_name)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.DS_Store' -> ''
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `endswith()`:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    if f.endswith(".jpeg"):
        new_name = f[9:]
        os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def listdir(path):
    for fn in os.listdir(path):
        if not fn.startswith('.'):
            yield fn
```